# Firebase Hosting Redirect to Sub-Folder

Tags: firebase, url, redirect, firebase-hosting

I have a project that use `domain.app` as primary domain, but I also want to redirect:

- `domain.com` > `domain.app/en/`
- `domain.de` > `domain.app/de/`

When I try this in firebase hosting interface, I get an error that this is not an valid URL:

[image]

This is ofc just an example domain to explain my problem. So... How I can solve this?